# Could not load file or assembly 'BundleTransformer.Core

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error in Bundle.config for

`var cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();`

I have installed `Install-Package BundleTransformer.Core -Version 1.9.92.0`

But still I am getting the same error. Please let me know how I resolve this issue?

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'BundleTransformer.Core, Version=1.9.92.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=973c344c93aac60d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

[image]

Comment: Make sure the class compiled without any errors.  Usually this error occurs because the referenced dll didn't fully compile.  Check the timestamp of the reference dll.  Also make sure you are getting from the correct folder debug/release.  Often people take the release version when the compiler is set to build only the debug dll.

Comment: Hi Jdweng, I followed your instruction but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Is the dll using any other dll's?  There are two different type of dlls.  One Windows95 and newer. Second prior to Windows95.  I had issue recently where I need two dlls.  One a Windows95 dll (ritten in c++) that was a wrapper for an older type dll.  I needed to have both dlls in the debug/release folder.